# selection an option from dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How to select ubuntu from the following drop down box

```
<select><option value=""></option>
   <option value="" selected="selected">Select Image</option>
   <option value="3f2cb990-cd0e-4bfa-a23e-54701498a2e5" data-volume_size="2">ubuntu-12.04-server-cloudimg-amd64 (1.4 GB)</option>
</select>
```

I tried the following still this doesnt work

```
$('#id_image_id').find('option:contains("Ubuntu"):contains("12.04")').prop('selected',true) || $('#id_image_id').find('option:contains("ubuntu"):contains("12.04")').prop('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("select").val("3f2cb990-cd0e-4bfa-a23e-54701498a2e5");
```

or

```
$('select option[value="3f2cb990-cd0e-4bfa-a23e-54701498a2e5"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

**To get By text: that contains ubuntu**

```
 $('select').find('option:contains("ubuntu")').prop('selected', true);
```

**To get that contents ubuntu as well as 12.04**

```
 $('select').find('option:contains("ubuntu"):contains("12.04")').prop('selected', true);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7aWYb/)**

Comment: I dont wanto to do it by val since it may change

Comment: can i also check for the text conatining ubuntu and 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Since `:contains` selector is case-sensitive, you can only use:

```
$('#id_image_id').find('option:contains("ubuntu"):contains("12.04")').prop('selected', true);
```

---

Based on your comment, you need to extend the current method of `:contains` selector:

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2y6Lm/)**

**[Reference](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/)**

Comment: how to search for case insensitive in this case

Comment: Dont know whats wrong the code doest seem to work .will update

Answer (score 0):

#### Check this <kbd>**[Working Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VX5SW/5/)**</kbd>

```
$("select#id_image_id option").filter(":contains('ubuntu')").prop('selected',true);
```

your mistake is you are not define **`Id`** and another things **`filter contains`** is **`strongly case sensitive`**

---

Another way also you can done same things,

```
$('select option[value="3f2cb990-cd0e-4bfa-a23e-54701498a2e5"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VX5SW/)**</kbd>

---

```
$(function() {
    $("#valget").val('3f2cb990-cd0e-4bfa-a23e-54701498a2e5');
});
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VX5SW/2/)**</kbd>